# Split array into equally distributed arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am trying to create 4 Arrays from 1 array, the condition is that the elements must be equally distributed.

```
const users = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const userBatch = new Array(4).fill([]);
users.forEach((user, index) => {
   userBatch[index % 4].push(user);
});
```

the expected out put is `userBatch`

```
[
 [1, 5],
 [2, 6],
 [3],
 [4]
]
```

but its not happening, the value of `userBatch` is

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
]
```

What is the error in this code?

-Update
It works in this way

```
const users = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const userBatch = [[],[],[],[]];
users.forEach((user, index) => {
   userBatch[index % 4].push(user);
});
```

Can anybody please explain why?

Comment: Don't use `.fill` with non-primitives; doing that creates a *single* of the passed object in memory. Then, when you iterate over the array, if you mutate the object at any index, it'll appear that every index object gets mutated, because all indicies point to the same object. Use `Array.from` instead

Comment: because your fill give four times the same array reference

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Although that duplicate helps explain why the original approach doesn't work, I think this question is equally about how to write code that does work.  I'd suggest reopening.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That question *does* show how to write code that does work - just change the `.fill` to `Array.from` instead. Can't use `.fill` with non-primitives (in most cases).

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I find that questionable.  But as my notions on closing [don't seem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400841) to be [the norm here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398720), I'll just leave it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and define the number to create the number of nested array

```js
const users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const userBatch = Array.from({
  length: 4
}, (v, i) => []);
users.forEach((user, index) => {
  userBatch[index % 4].push(user);
});
console.log(userBatch)
```